# Set legend in seaborn after pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, legend

I have to plot two distplots from a dataframe based on a binary variable:

```
df_train \
.groupby("Binary")["Continuous"] \
.apply(sb.distplot, hist=False)

plt.show()
```

If I pass the argument *label=* in apply, the same label will be applied to both the plots. How can I tell him to show the label based on the value of the binary feature?

Comment: Could you give an example of `df_train`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `apply`, you could loop through the created group. (Instead of `distplot` without histogram, `kdeplot` can be called directly, which makes it easier to provide additional parameters.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df_train = pd.DataFrame({"Binary": np.repeat(['yes', 'no'], 1000),
                         "Continuous": np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 2000).cumsum()})
groups = df_train.groupby("Binary")["Continuous"]

for label, group in groups:
    sns.kdeplot(group, label=f"Binary: {label}", shade=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]